# I can't open HeidiSQL

Tags: heidisql, mariadb-10.6

I used MariaDB and HeidiSQL without error nor problems before trying import some sql dump.
But When I try to import sql dump, it says about 'Out of Memory' and closed with system error message and it doesn't open.
After that error, when I click 'open' at HeidiSQL session manage, it close automaticaly.
I remove MariaDB and reinstalled but nothing change.
What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. It caused by out of memory. It just took so long time, not an error.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the documentation](https://www.heidisql.com/help.php#import), you should use the "Run SQL file" menu item, not "Load file".

"Running" means the file is loaded in smaller chunks which get executed directly. "Loading" puts the whole file in the query editor, which easily eats all of your memory with a larger file.